# I can use Ironpython in my workplace lap but not in my personal pc, with Visual Studio Code 2022

Tags: visual-studio-code, ironpython

I want to use iron python with visual code in my home pc, the problem is that I can not, the weird thing is that in the laptop which I work I can do it, I do not know what could be missing in my home laptop settings.

I have installed de 2.7.12 iron python version and the VS Code detects it with out problems in my work pc.

Work PC, Iron python works well
[image]

Test iron python script
[image]
But with the same iron python version in my home laptop I am getting the error "Invalid python interpreter selected".

any idea of why iron python works in a pc but not in the other?

Comment: Visual Studio **Code** doesn't have a version 2022 (that would be the **full** Visual Studio) - the current VS Code version is v1.80

Comment: Adding to @marc_s comment ... (non-code) Visual Studio (Python Tools for Visual Studio) no longer supports IronPython. And while vscode might be happy to launch your IronPython projects as far as I know debugging and more advanced integrations are not available.